# Facebook application request issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

im trying to test example from developers webpage

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . facebook::getConfig( 'appId' ) .
    "&client_secret=" . facebook::getConfig( 'secret' ) .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";
 $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);   
 $user_id = "100002758712176";
 $apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='test string'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";
$result = file_get_contents(urlencode($apprequest_url));
echo "App Request sent? ". $result;
```

and got eror [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
when i use $apprequest_url in browser all works . Where is the problem ?

Comment: Is your Facebook user logged into your application?  You can only request an access token after the user has authenticated your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should urlencode the string you are sending in url:

```
$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $user_id . "/apprequests?message=" . urlencode('test string') . "&" . $app_access_token . "&method=post";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something looks weird...

```
$result = file_get_contents(urlencode($apprequest_url));
```

First off, it looks like you are encoding the entire url. Second, your url string contains $app_access_token, but it is not bound to a param key... Might want to try only URL encoding the "message" and adding "access_token" to your url stirng:

```
$message = urlencode('test string');
$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/apprequests?";
$apprequest_url .= "message=$message&access_token=$app_access_token&method=post";
```